# How to save shell screen to file verbose?

Tags: shell

Need to keep a copy of what has been already output to the screen (i.e. the standard output), in shells of both Linux and OS X. Better if the colored text can be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the menu command `Shell > Export Text As...`.

You can also use the Unix `script` command to save everything automatically as it's happening.

Comment: Im not on a Mac right now, but can't you do something like `cmd + s`? I know it saves something, but Im not sure what it would save

Comment: Okay. Was about to answer that, but I wasn't quite sure if there wasn't a better option. Now I know what Im doing when I accidentally hit the combination

Answer (score 1):

Run your command through `tee` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tee.1.html)):

```
$ mycommand | tee ~/Documents/output.txt
```

This will output to both the screen and to the file specified on the `tee` command line and will work in any terminal session (i.e. ssh, not just Terminal.app).